# django - how to add additional parameters to queryset in forms

Tags: django, forms, django-queryset

i want to add additional parameters to the queryset in forms

```
class Reserve(forms.ModelForm):

    food_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Food.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None, day=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Reserve, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.year = kwargs.pop('year')
        self.month = kwargs.pop('month')
        self.day = kwargs.pop('day')
        self.fields['food_name'].queryset = Food.objects.filter(
            serve_date__year = year, serve_date__month = month, serve_date__day = day)

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ('food_count', 'food_name')
```

but its return KeyError:

```
'year'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Year is an explicit keyword parameter here, it isn't in kwargs.

```
 self.year = year
```

And so on for the other parameters you've listed explicitly.